# Iterate specific JSONObject with no keys

Tags: loops, json

Can anyone help me how to iterate this kind of JSON

http://104.236.54.235/api/v1/preguntas

i need to get all stuff inside a table database, but no idea how.

Thnx

Comment: Can you clarify what kind of database you would like to insert it in to.  Also what language are you using to traverse the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over JSONArray and for each JSONObject get the keys like id,pregunta...etc.

```
              JSONArray jAttrArr = new JSONArray(jsonString);

                    for(int j=0;j<jAttrArr.length();j++){
                        JSONObject jObject = jAttrArr.getJSONObject(j);

                        String id = (String) jObject.get("id");
                        String pregunta= (String)jObject.get("pregunta");
                        ...
                     }
```